# How to escape backslash c# xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, connection-string

I've been looking around trying to find a solution to escape a backslash and insert it into my connection string and none of the solutions I found around the web are working.

```
public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        string connectionString =$"Data Source={ServerAddress};Initial Catalog={DatabaseName};User ID={Username};Password={ Password}";
        int lastIndex = connectionString.IndexOf("\\");
        connectionString = connectionString.Remove(lastIndex, 1);
        connectionString = connectionString.Insert(lastIndex, @"\");
        return connectionString;
    }
```

I even tried removing the double backslash and inserting a single one but still the same double back slash is inserted, any ideas?

Comment: you mean you only want a single backslash in the `int lastindex`?

Comment: Yes I only want  a single backslash, but it seems they are treated as one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You use the `IndexOf` function for the `lastIndex` variable, perhaps you would like to use `String.LastIndexOf`;
2. The `"\\"` is equivalent of `@"\"`. So the sequence of functions `IndexOf`, `Remove`, `Insert` do not make any changes;
3. Since the backslash is a control character, it must be escaped, so `"\\"` means one backslash. To see the text without control characters, use the "Text Visualizer" window

[image: Screenshot].

Perhaps your problem is not related to escaping a backslash.

Comment: Ok Thanks Artem, I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: I had a look at the connection string  in the text visualizer and you are in fact right, in the text visualizer it shows just one backslash, but the program crashes when I try to open the connection to the database and the exception message is "Input string was not in a correct format.". This is how the connection string looks - "Data Source=192.168.1.200,1433\\ETIENNELAPTOP;Initial Catalog=posworx;User ID=sa;Password=@P0sW0rx2011"

Comment: @CliftonSteenkamp you've posted your username and password there

Comment: @CliftonSteenkamp, Could you please attach a screenshot of the exception?

Comment: Ohkay just give me a moment

Comment: Bleh its ohkay, I don't mind the username and password, do you want the stack trace?

Comment: stack trace is null